# SSIS package locking temp table

Tags: ssis, temp-tables

Ok I have a package that first creates a temp file in Sequence Container and then inserts data into the table. Data is then entered into two different temp tables in two different Sequence Containers and then I have a Data Flow Task that inserts more data into the first temp table but it seems to have locked it and I cannot access it at all but it will not error out. It just keeps acting like it's waiting for it to be available.

Below is screenshot with red highlights to show where table is created and then where it stalls when trying to insert data. Below that is the flow control that is yellow.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what your control flow looks like? Are you using the built-in transaction capability of SSIS?

Comment: We used sql statements to insert data. Not sure what you mean by SSIS built in transaction capability.

Comment: are you sure it's blocking?  also, here's some info on ssis-transactions...
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/01/31/SSIS_3A00_-Beware-of-transactions.aspx

Comment: As far as I can tell it is blocking because when I try to get meta-data for the table or to select from it the select just sits and spins.

Comment: I believe this to be the process that is blocked. 64    SUSPENDED                      NADECORP\KLynch PC06007  73    ANALYST_ENV SELECT           0 0 09/28 08:52:42 Microsoft SQL Server                           64    0

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the Lookup task there. What table is it attempting to perform lookups against? How many rows are in it?

Comment: Well first it doesn't even make it to the Lookup task it hangs in the initial query but to answer your question the lookup only pulls 521 records and I was able to run it in 2 seconds manually. The only note I would add is that it is coming from an Oracle db but that should not matter.

Comment: If you look in your logs though, as part of the ... onpreexecute, I think, event, the lookup task will be the first thing that runs in that data flow and it will be busy caching data from your lookup. That's gotta complete before the dataflow gets the signal to start and the OLE DB Source goes from white to yellow. My theory was that perhaps the "hang" you are experiencing is due to oddities with the Lookup task. If you change the Cache Mode on that transformation from Full (Default) to either Partial or None, does that make a difference?

Comment: No it has not made any difference. This is at the end of the logs.  
Information: 0x40043006 at Load data into PEACE Staging, DTS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Load data into PEACE Staging, DTS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.